# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Unable to deploy adapter and app with ant task

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am attempting to do a simple build and deploy of a worklight adapter using an Ant Task.

Here is the task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<project name="Project" default="buildAndDeployAdapters" basedir=".">  
    <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">  
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\DownloadDirector\CIN0VEN\worklight-ant.jar"/>  
        </classpath>  
    </taskdef>  

    <target name="buildAndDeployAdapters">
        <adapter-builder folder="adapters\ProjectAdapter" destinationfolder="bin"/>
        <adapter-deployer worklightserverhost="http://localhost:10080" deployable="bin\ProjectAdapter.adapter" />
    </target>
</project>
```

The build succeeds, but when the deploy occurs I get the error message:

`build.xml:11: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`

If I go to http:// localhost:10080 on my browser, I successfully hit the Web Sphere page. I have verified that the path to the ProjectAdapter.adapter is correct as well. I have tried deploying my application the same way and it also gets the same error. I can deploy in eclipse just fine by right clicking the adapter or application and deploy.

I'm using the worklight Eclipse plugin, version 6.0.0.20130701-1413. I recently upgraded from the worklight free developer editon to the Enterprise Edition in order to do these build tasks. What could be the problem? Perhaps I did not upgrade properly? My goal is to run some other tasks before I build and deploy, but first I need to get build and deploy working.

Thanks!

Comment: You need the context root of the servlet.  like servername:080/worklight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by tik27, in Worklight 6.0 there is now also a default context root in the `worklightserverhost` path.

The context root by default is the project name. For example:

```
<adapter-deployer worklightserverhost="http://localhost:10080/mytestproject" deployable="bin\ProjectAdapter.adapter" />
```

The [documentation does not yet](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_adapters.html) state this, but it has been fixed internally and pending re-publication.

Also see:

- [IBM Worklight 6.0 - worklightserverhost attribute and the app-builder Ant task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682630/ibm-worklight-6-0-worklightserverhost-attribute-and-the-app-builder-ant-task)

Answer (score 0):

another common reason for java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in deployment is bad form upload. the correct format is below:
lets assume the binaries are located on /tmp/workspace6.3/proj1/bin/
using the curl unix utility we can deploy

### adapters:

`curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"  -F "file=@/tmp/workspace6.3/proj1/bin/sampleAdapter.adapter" --user admin:admin -H "Accept: application/json"  http://localhost:10080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/proj1/adapters`

### wlapps:

`curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"  -F "file=@/tmp/workspace6.3/proj1/bin/app1-all.wlapp" --user admin:admin -H "Accept: application/json"  http://localhost:10080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/proj1/applications?locale`